# Error with Expo CLI 2.0 running ios simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, expo

[image: error message when I run ios simulator]

- dev. environment
- OS: Mac OS
- npm version: 4.6.1

I simply init the project with command `expo init my-app` and start the project.

Then, I select the `Run on ios server` and get the error message like in the above image.

Is there anyone who can fix this error?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error with restarting my Mac